# reading a FILE* with (hopefully standard) C++ tools?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to read the output from another program from my program. To do that, I can use popen(). This way, I get a FILE* to the program's output that can be parsed in my program. How can I read and parse the content of the return value of popen() from my program? Alternatively, is there a more C++-like version of popen somewhere?

Comment: See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). You probably want to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either create a stream buffer doing the moral equivalent of `popen()` or you can create a stream buffer wrapping `FILE*`. Once you got a stream buffer, you can use it with `std::istream` which seems to be what you intend to do. A simple (and untested) stream buffer reading from a `FILE*` would look something like this:

```
struct FILEbuf
    : std::streambuf {
    FILEbuf(FILE* fp): fp_(fp) {}
    int underflow() {
        if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) {
            int size = fread(this->buffer_, 1, s_size, this->fp_);
            if (0 < size) {
                this->setg(this->buffer_, this->buffer_, this->buffer_ + size);
            }
        }
        return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
            ? traits_type::eof()
            : traits_type::to_int_type(*gptr());
     }
     FILE* fp_;
     enum { s_size = 1024 };
     char  buffer_[s_size];
};
```

I reckon I mistyped something but roughly the idea does work: Just read from the `FILE*` into a stream buffer. Alternatively, create a stream reading from a spawned process. This take a couple of platform specific calls to `fork()`, `exec..()`, `pipe()`, `close()`, `dup2()` (probably forgot something here, too) but can be done as well.

A stream buffer like the one above could be used, e.g., like this:

```
int main()
{
    FILEbuf      sbuf(fopen("pstream.cpp", "r"));
    std::istream in(&sbuf);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a C++ wrapper over `FILE*` called `stdio_filebuf` (GNU implementation) or `stdiobuf`. I think it's not a standardized thing, but if you google for `stdiobuf` you'll find that it's available on many platforms. Here is a working example of how to use it with a `FILE*` pointer returned from `popen`, compiled with gcc 4.5.0 and tested on a Linux box:

```
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE* f = popen("ls", "r");
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fdbuf(f, std::ios::in);

    std::ifstream in;
    in.std::ios::rdbuf(&fdbuf);

    string s;
    in >> s;
    cout << s;

    pclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```